# call jspdf using vuejs2

Tags: vuejs2, jspdf

How can I call the jsPDF javascript using vuejs?

```
var doc = new jsPDF();
var specialElementHandlers = {
  '#editor': function (element, renderer) {
     return true;
   }
};
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all you can create custom directive (`Vue.directive`) for js pdf.
ex.

```
<your public directory path>/js_pdf.js
```

```
 Vue.directive('js-pdf', {
        twoWay: true,
        priority: 1000,
        deep: true,
        params: ['pdfvalue', "pdfname"], //Add your require variable
        paramWatchers: {

        },

        bind: function () {
            //As per your wish you can set condition
            var self = this;
            setTimeout(function () {
                var doc = new jsPDF()
                doc.text(self.params.pdfvalue, 10, 10)
                doc.save(self.params.pdfname + '.pdf');
            }, 10);

        },
        update: function (value) {
            //As per your requirement you can change data on update method
            var self = this;
            setTimeout(function () {
            }, 10);
        },

        unbind: function () {
        }

    });
```

Now you can include this file in your index.html file and also include jsPDF library

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jspdf/1.3.4/jspdf.debug.js"></script>
<script src="<your public directory path>/js_pdf.js"></script>
```

Next you can use this directive with your element
ex.

```
<input type="hidden" id="editor" v-js-pdf pdfvalue="Hello world how are" pdfname="document">//Here "v-js-pdf" is our custom directive
```

Currently i have added hidden field and take static value but you can add dynamic value as per your requirement and you can take any other html element as per your requirement